# PHP - Find max/highest value

Tags: php, pdo

I have this query:

```
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare("select round((expire - unix_timestamp()) / 86400) as days, count(*) as cnt from xeon_users_rented WHERE user_by=:username group by days;");
    $stmt->bindParam(":username",$userdata['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data=$stmt->fetchAll();
```

Which returns this array result `var_dump($data)`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["days"]=>
    string(2) "27"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "27"
    ["cnt"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["days"]=>
    string(3) "116"
    [0]=>
    string(3) "116"
    ["cnt"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

I then want to get the highest value of the `$data` result:

```
echo max($data["days"]);
```

Althoug that doesn't work, as nothing is getting echoed out.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If downvoting (closing), please be so kind to give me a reason. As a PHP beginner, I can't see anything wrong with my question.

Comment: `echo max(array_column($data,'days'));` if you're using PHP >= 5.5

Comment: @MarkBaker Damn, now there's a useful function I had no idea about. I'm glad you mentioned it.

Comment: You realise that PHP 5.3 is at end-of-life and no longer supported? Perhaps you should consider upgrading

Comment: @George - your answer uses the best alternative to array_column() for earlier versions of PHP

Comment: As you are only selecting 2 columns and not doing any sorting, you could also order by `days` and get the maximum `days` value of the last result using `end()` (or the first item, depending on your sort order...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data['days']` isn't an array. You have an array of arrays, each of which has its own 'days' element.

You could map your 'days' elements to an array and then get the `max()`:

```
echo max(array_map(function($d){
    return $d['days'];
}, $data));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/217358)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to `return` inside the `array_map()` function. Please try now.

Answer (score 4):

wouldn't

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Do that in query already?
Selecting only the highest value - therefor saving bandwidth and wont require  loops to waste even more resources.
All tho i cannot test it with your specific query.

Answer (score 0):

As i see your array is 2 dimensional, you need to loop through both of this array and then get max from them.

```
for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($data);$i++) { echo max($data[$i]["days"]); }
```

This should solve your problems.

Comment: This is incorrect because as George stated, the value of the `days` index is not an array.  This will currently output for each element of the `$data` array.